# SQL Native Client & OLEDB

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a Windows 2008 server with SQL Server 2005 SP3 with a bunch of classic ASP sites that are using SQLOLEDB to connect.

We have a new application that requires SQL Server Native Client 2008 R2 installed because it is using the SQLSRV PHP Driver. SQL Server Native Client 2005 is already installed (as part of SQL Server install).

Are there any issues with installing SQL Server Native Client 2008 R2 and connecting using SQLOLEDB? I'm assuming that 2008 client is backward compatible with the 2005 client?

Can the 2008 client be uninstalled back to 2005 if we need to roll-back?

I'm concerned that installing this could cause issues for the sites already using OLEDB.
Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install them side by side no problem.

> Are there any issues with installing SQL Native Client 2008 R2 and
>   connecting using SQLOLEDB?

No (apart from the lower functionality set of SQLOLEDB)

> I'm assuming that 2008 client is backward compatible with the 2005
>   client?

Yes.

> Can the 2008 client be uninstalled back to 2005 if we need to
>   roll-back

Yes

Comment: Thanks, fingers crossed then ;)